# Woocommerce custom tabs with data from simple and variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, product-variations

I'm displaying fitment information on a custom tab in woocommerce for simple and variable products with this particular data.

**Here's what I have done that is working:**

1. Display custom tab for products
2. Only products with data will display the tab
3. The tab only shows data for the variation that is selected
4. Added custom field in admin for each variation to enter data

**This is what I am having trouble with:**

6. Add a custom field in admin for simple products (Maybe variable parent products too)
7. Display this in the frontend custom tab when available

**Here's my code so far:**

// Custom tab and field for variations and simple products //

```
// Add custom field to variations
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options', 'add_custom_field_to_variations', 10, 3 );
function add_custom_field_to_variations( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    echo '<div class="fitments">';
        woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
            'id' => 'fitments[' . $loop . ']',
            'class' => 'short',
            'label' => __( 'Fitments', 'woo' ),
            'wrapper_class' => 'form-field form-row form-row-first',
            'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'fitments', true )
        ));
    echo '</div>';
}

    // Save custom field on product variation save
    add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_custom_field_variations', 10, 2 );
    function save_custom_field_variations( $variation_id, $i ) {
        $fitments = $_POST['fitments'][$i];
        if ( isset( $fitments ) ) update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'fitments', esc_attr( $fitments ) );
}

// Add custom product data to tab
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'fitments_tab' );
function fitments_tab( $tabs ) {
   
    // Requesting the meta fields
        global $post;
        $product_fitments = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fitments', true );
    
    // Checking if the meta fields have content. If no content, the tab doesn't show on the product
        if ( ! empty( $product_fitments ) )
    
            // Adds the new tab
    $tabs['fitments_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Fitments ', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 10,
        'callback'  => 'fitments_tab_content'
    );
    return $tabs;
}

function fitments_tab_content() {
    global $product;
    
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        
        // Loop through the variation IDs
        foreach( $product->get_children() as $key => $variation_id ) {
            
            // Get an instance of the WC_Product_Variation Object
            $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
            
            // Get meta
            $fitments = $variation->get_meta( 'fitments' );
            
            // Output
            echo '<div class="fitments_tab_content fitments_tab_content-' . $variation_id .'">';
            if ( $fitments ) {
                echo '<p>' . $fitments . '</p>';
            }
            if ( ! empty( $product_fitments ) ) {
            echo '<h2>' . esc_html__( 'Fitments', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h2>';
            echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $product_fitments );
        }
            echo '</div>';
        }
        ?>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // Hide all
            $( '.fitments_tab_content' ).css( 'display', 'none' );

            // Change
            $( 'input.variation_id' ).change( function() {
                
                // Hide all
                $( '.fitments_tab_content' ).css( 'display', 'none' );
                if( $( 'input.variation_id' ).val() != '' ) {
                    var var_id = $( 'input.variation_id' ).val();

                    // Display current
                    $( '.fitments_tab_content-' + var_id ).css( 'display', 'block' );
                }
            });    
        });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```